# How to change to "Next page" on Google storage api?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm using this API(https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/$bucketId/o/) to fetch data from my bucket, but I found out that List is incomplete and a "**nextPageToken**" is returned to me too.

I [googled it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) and it appear to be the key to next page, but I tried to put it into the Header or put it to the URL afterward(eg: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/$bucketId/o/pageToken=Ci1yZXZxagenuio46432abt8IamwMi5jc3Y=), they didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to do that? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. It's a URL parameter, so add a question mark:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/$bucketId/o?pageToken=Ci1yZXZxagenuio46432abt8IamwMi5jc3Y=
```